# Estou sendo vítima de algum hacker?

Tags: bash, terminal

Olá, sou iniciante no mundo da tecnologia e estou desconfiado de alguns arquivos que apareceram na minha Home no Ubuntu. Isso porque não havia visto esses arquivos antes.

São eles *.mozilla*,*.cache*,*.config*,*.bash_history*,*.local* entre outros. Com destaque para o *.local* que eu não consegui excluir. O erro se deu porque neste arquivo está a lixeira "Trash", ou seja,"'Trash' can't be put in Trash". E sempre que eu excluo os outros, eles voltam para a Home. Sei que alguns arquivos ali são importantes, como o *.bash_history*, mas eu achei estranho eles aparecerem na minha Home sendo que isso nunca tinha acontecido.

Se puderem ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Não tem hacker nenhum, são arquivos normais do sistema: https://askubuntu.com/q/14535 | https://superuser.com/q/473626